# DB2 i 7.3: writing stored procedures that loop (with date variable) insert values from select

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, db2-400

I'm having problem to create procedure in db2 i 7.3. The main ideia is to a given end date (should be today) to insert values to specific table from selected that results match with fist_day(end date - 3 years) and last_day(end date - 3 years) for every month until today.

Is currently returning this error: ***14:19:25  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -199, SQL State: 42601]  [SQL0199] Palavra-chave FOR não esperada. Testemunhos válidos: ;.
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]***
Above my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYLIB.SP_DIFJURO () 
LANGUAGE SQL
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE DATAJURO DATE DEFAULT NULL;

FOR DATAJURO > (SELECT CURRENT_DATE - 3 YEAR FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
DO
INSERT INTO MYLIB.SDDIFJUROD (CONTAJURO, JUROCALC, JURODEBIT, DATAINICIO, DATAFIM)
SELECT NCJCCONTA, totaljurocalculado, NCLJVLRJ, LEFT(CHAR(LAST_DAY(DATAJURO), ISO),8)||'01', LAST_DAY(DATAJURO)  FROM ( SELECT SUM(valorjurocalculado) totaljurocalculado, a.NCJCCONTA from
(SELECT C.NCJCCONTA NCJCCONTA, C.NCJCDTPRO, C.NCJCDTJUR,
       CASE 
              WHEN R.NCJCTREG = 'R' THEN R.NCJCSLDV
              ELSE C.NCJCSLDV
       END saldodatavalor,
       CASE 
              WHEN R.NCJCTREG = 'R' THEN round(R.NCJCTXC,2)
              ELSE round(C.NCJCTXC,2)
       END taxadiaria, decimal(round((ifnull(R.NCJCSLDV, C.NCJCSLDV)*ifnull(R.NCJCTXC, C.NCJCTXC)/100)/360,2),15,2) valorjurocalculado
FROM (
SELECT NCJCCONTA, NCJCDTPRO, NCJCDTJUR, NCJCTREG, NCJCSLDV, NCJCMOED, NCJCTXC FROM MYLIB.LOGJR 
WHERE NCJCDTJUR BETWEEN LEFT(VARCHAR_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(DATAJURO), 'YYYYMMDD'),6)||'01' AND VARCHAR_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(DATAJURO), 'YYYYMMDD') 
AND NCJCCLCP = 'DO' AND NCJCTREG = 'C' AND NCJCNUMVD < 0 ) C
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT NCJCCONTA, NCJCDTPRO, NCJCDTJUR, NCJCTREG, NCJCSLDV, NCJCMOED, NCJCTXC FROM MYLIB.LOGJR 
WHERE NCJCDTJUR BETWEEN LEFT(VARCHAR_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(DATAJURO), 'YYYYMMDD'),6)||'01' AND VARCHAR_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(DATAJURO), 'YYYYMMDD') 
AND NCJCCLCP = 'DO' AND NCJCTREG = 'R' AND NCJCNUMVD < 0) R
ON C.NCJCCONTA = R.NCJCCONTA AND C.NCJCDTJUR = R.NCJCDTJUR
) a group by a.NCJCCONTA
)jurocalc
INNER JOIN MYLIB.LJRDC ON NCLJCONTA = NCJCCONTA 
AND LEFT(NCLJBUFFER, 16) = LEFT(VARCHAR_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(DATAJURO), 'YYYYMMDD'),6)||'01'||VARCHAR_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(DATAJURO), 'YYYYMMDD') 
WHERE int(ABS(totaljurocalculado)) != int(ABS(NCLJVLRJ));
SET DATAJURO = (SELECT DATAJURO - 1 MONTH FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1);
END FOR;
END
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see any question in your "question".

Comment: i'm having problems to create procedure that procedure. 

 _14:19:25  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -199, SQL State: 42601]  [SQL0199] Palavra-chave FOR não esperada. Testemunhos válidos: ;.
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]_

Comment: You are missing statetement terminators. Each SQL statement in a routine must be terminated with a semicolon. That's on top of your other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong use of `FOR` statement.

`FOR` in SQL/PL doesn't look like `for loop` in some programming language like c or java. You must use a `SELECT` statement with `FOR`, which iterates the result set of this `SELECT` providing you an ability to reference the corresponding column values in the statements inside the body of `FOR` by cursor name `C1`.
In the example below the `SELECT` statement using Recursive Common Table Expression returns the last day of every month from `CURRENT_DATE - 3 YEARS` to `CURRENT_DATE`. You may run this `SELECT` standalone to check / slightly modify its condition to return exact list of dates needed.
Note, that you don't use a `SET` statement to increment your "loop variable" `C1.DATAJURO`, since the `SELECT` statement handles this.

```
FOR C1 AS
WITH DATES (DT) AS
(
VALUES FIRST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE)
  UNION ALL
SELECT DT - 1 MONTH
FROM DATES
WHERE DT > CURRENT_DATE - 3 YEAR
)
SELECT LAST_DAY(DT) AS DATAJURO
FROM DATES
DO
  INSERT INTO MYLIB.SDDIFJUROD ...
  ... C1.DATAJURO ...
END FOR;
```